# Scroll text up (like in credits) then reverse and scroll text down?

Tags: video-editor, software-recommendation

Unsure if this is the right "sub-Stack Exchange" for this question, however I've been unable to find a way to scroll a block of text up then reverse it and scroll down after similar to "The Future of Publishing - by DK (UK)"

Or "Lost Generation"

I've tried with Movie Maker (I have a Windows 8 laptop) but if there's some other program that I can get this done with then I'm happy to try it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After Effects or just about any titling software should allow this easily.  You just need to make a layer with all the text on it (or even an image) then you simply need to apply a motion effect to scroll from the top to bottom, put a keyframe in the middle and then the keyframe at the end should bring it back.  This should produce exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: Was able to get it working with After Effects, now to figure out a fade area in the top and bottom of the composition so it scrolls and fades in :) Cheers

Comment: @dan2k3k4 - the easiest bet, use a mask with a gradient to make the top and bottom edges blend with the background.